# XAML Listbox reference elements

Tags: silverlight, xaml

On a button click I'm trying to iterate this list in the codebehind and access the `checkboxApproved` element

```
<ListBox x:Name="listGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=ReviewsDataSourceT32c}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions />
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    ...
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Platform}"/>                    
                <CheckBox Name="checkboxApproved"  Grid.Column="3" />
```

codebehind

```
foreach (var item in listGroups.ItemsSource)
{
    if (item.checkboxApproved == checked) { ... }
}
```

This doesn't work, as am referencing the bound object from the datasource.

The `checkboxApproved` isn't currently bound.  One approach could be to use a PresentationModel and pass this along, then access via ItemsSource as above.  I'd like to keep simple if possible and just reference it like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have gone with the presentationModel approach